# Linux Send Mail - Command Line

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I have a little script on Centos 6.5 64 bit which sends email content of a text file (as inline and NOT as attachment) to a user:

```
mail -s "Zabbix Alerts" -r sender@mydomain.com receiver@mydomain.com < /filename
```

It used to work great for a long time. Today we have got a new server Centos 6.7 64bit and the same scripts sends what is expected but not as inline but as attachment.

We need the content of the text file as inline text (not attachment).

I have already spent a few hours find the cause but no luck.

I will be really thankful if someone can help me.

Comment: It maybe just about the selinux. Have you checked it ?

Comment: selinux is disabled. You know it is sending the email but as attachment whereas I need it as text (body of the email)

Comment: I just found it is some problem with the text file. When I open it in vi it shows too many ^M characters. When I remove that it becomes fine. So it is not a problem with mail but the file

Answer (score 0):

I just found it is some problem with the text file. When I open it in vi it shows too many ^M characters. When I remove that it becomes fine. So it is not a problem with mail but the file